# How to refer on an object id inside a predicate?

Tags: ios, core-data

I need to connect 2 entites. The first one - `Player` (attr = "name"), the second - `Profiles` (attr: "player_id", "command_id" and other stuff). There is a relationship `"player"` between Profiles and Player. I want to show the Profile entity but with players names instead of player_ids. player_id is `[[[_player objectID] URIRepresentation] absoluteString]`. How should I call `[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"player_id==player.<object id>"]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initital approach was wrong. NSManagedObject subclassed objects should be used instead of their ids.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be after is Apple's predicate variable substitution.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html

Scroll down to "Cocoa Fundamental" and check the code to see how Apple does it.